# defaulting unmatched backrefrences in perl or sed

Tags: regex, perl, sed

Is there a way to default back referenced variables `$1`, `$2` and `$3` here ?

```
start="a" hi="1"  bye="2"
start="b" bye="3"
start="c" hi="4"
```

I am using this command to  filter out:

```
perl-ne 'print if s/.*start="([^"]+).*?hi="([^"]+).*?bye="([^"]+).*/$1 $2 $3/g'
a 1 2
```

Is there a way to generate below result :

```
a 1 2
b null 3
c 4 null
```

I also searched for defaulting a back referenced variable but no working solution  about  it on that front. Eg,  in bash we use `${var:-null}` to default the `var` to a string `null`.

Comment: No, backreferences always point to the text present in the input string. Use code logic to manipulate matches. In Perl, use `e` flag to be able to use code in the RHS, and adjust the pattern to match the optional fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```sh
$ perl -nE 'my %vals=();
            while (m/(\w+)="([^"]+)"/g) { $vals{$1} = $2 }
            printf "%s %s %s\n", $vals{start}, $vals{hi}//"null", $vals{bye}//"null"
           ' input.txt
a 1 2
b null 3
c 4 null
```

---

Splits up the input into individual key/value pairs, saves them in a hash table, and then prints out the values using the `//` operator, which returns the left hand argument if it's defined, otherwise the right hand argument.

---

Variation if `start`, `hi` and `bye` are the only keys you can have and they always appear in that order:

```sh
$ perl -ne 'm/start="([^"]+)"(?:\s+hi="([^"]+)")?(?:\s+bye="([^"]+)")?/;
            printf "%s %s %s\n", $1, $2//"null", $3//"null"' input.txt
a 1 2
b null 3
c 4 null
```

Uglier regular expression that makes the hi and bye parts optional matches.

Answer (score 6):

The special number variables (`$1` etc) get introduced for [capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Capture-groups) even if their subpatterns fail to match, when the capture groups are optional (otherwise the whole match fails if any one subpattern fails). Those without a match stay `undef`.

For example, if a pattern has three optional capture groups, like `(...)?`, then after the regex (or after the matching part in a substitution operator) *there will exist* all `$1,$2,$3` variables, some possibly being `undef` if their subpattern didn't match (that `?` still made those formally match, by there being zero occurrences of that pattern).

Then test each `$N` and if `undef` replace it with a desired phrase (`'null'` here)

```
perl -wnE'/
    (?: start \s*=\s* "([^"]+)"\s* )?
    (?: hi    \s*=\s* "([^"]+)"\s* )?
    (?: bye   \s*=\s* "([^"]+)"\s* )? /x; 
    say join " ", map { $_//"null" } ($1,$2,$3)
' file
```

(broken over lines and spaced-out for readability)    Since each term has the same structure the pattern can be prepared far more flexibly from a list of expected words.<sup>†</sup>

For the given sample `file` this prints

```
a 1 2
b null 3
c 4 null
```

---

<sup>†</sup>  This is an overkill for a specific case and in a one-liner but is useful in a more rounded script which may be used with different keyword sets, since all hard-coded input is in the definition of the input array (`@w`)

```
perl -wnE'
    BEGIN { 
        @w = qw(start hi bye);  # keywords to form a pattern with
        $re = join " ", 
              map { q{(?:} . $_ . q{\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"\s*)?} } @w;
    };  
    @m = /$re/x; 
    say join " ", map { $_//"null" } @m
' file
```

This prints the same for the given input `file`.  In `bash` shell it can simply be copy-pasted as it stands; in other shells you may need to make it back into one line, and remove comments. (Given as a command-line program, "one"-liner, for easy testing.)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^/start=null hi=null bye=null\n/  # insert a template
        :a                                  # loop name
        s/(\S+=)\S+(.*\n.*)\1"(\S+)"/\3\2/  # replace lookup with value
        ta                                  # repeat till failure
        s/\S+=//g                           # remove any template
        P                                   # print
        d' file                             # delete debris
```

Insert a template and loop replacing matches with original values.

When no more matches, remove any unmatched template keys and debris from the original line.